# Arduino IDE: array bound

Tags: arrays, arduino-ide

I get an **array bound error** in Arduino IDE for the following code. This can be solved if I put the outcome of the calculation for the "sample" (which is 50 in this case) but this is kind of dummy solution. I want the software to do it for myself not me doing hand calculations and insert it. What would be the workaround?   Thanks!

```
int des_freq=200; 
int ncycles=5;
int sample =1000/(des_freq*T); 
float V_sin_bip[sample]; // error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.6.6, Arduino IDE enables C++11 by default. But C++ standard (till C++11) doesn’t support variable-sized arrays. The C++11 standard mentions array size as a constant-expression.

`float V_sin_bip[sample];` uses variable expression to mention array size. Thus, an error occurs.

If you want a "variable-length array" (better called a "dynamically sized array" in C++, since proper variable-length arrays aren't allowed), you either have to dynamically allocate memory yourself:

```
int n = 10;
double* a = new double[n]; // Don't forget to delete [] a; when you're done!
```

Or, better yet, use a standard container:

```
int n = 10;
std::vector<double> a(n); // Don't forget to #include <vector>
```

If you still want a proper array, you can use a constant, not a variable, when creating it:

```
const int n = 10;
double a[n]; // now valid, since n isn't a variable (it's a compile time constant)
```